# Flexbox cropping and centering

Tags: css

I'm using Flexbox to center images in a box. It works well for smaller images that fit into `.item`, but larger images (>216px) are not centred and don't crop equally on all sides. What can I do?

```
.item {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    width: 216px;
    height: 216px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    justify-items: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.item img {
    background-color: #ccc;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`display: flex` will allow you to align content but the content won't overflow to the right or top without negative margin. In this circumstance I personally would use centered background images.

CSS:

```
.item {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    width: 216px;
    height: 216px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center; 
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="item" style="background-image:url('path/to/image.jpg')">
```

Comment: Thanks @rlbaxter – this works but the problem is that I do need to set the background color (dynamically) – and it seems as if it's not possible to use background-color and -image at the same time. Will try negative margin then. Thanks for the pointer!

Comment: You can use background image and background color together.
`<div class="item" style="background-image:url('path/to/image.jpg'); background-color:#FF0000">`

Comment: you are right. Strange, I had tested this and it did not work. I must have set up something wrong. This helped a lot. Thanks for taking the time!